# How to control service method invocations within component template

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-changedetection

I recently inherited an Angular 11 project and I'm not entirly sure that I understand all concepts properly.

**Context**

I am currently implementing a component that generates form fields based on the selection of a dropdown. I solved this using Reactive Forms and the FormBuilder (`formBuilder.array`) – all  encapsulated in a form service.

The `FormService` is responsible for managing form controls and other form releated stuff. It's injected into the component but its methods are consumed directly by the template.

```js
// DynamicFormComponent
constructor(public formService: FormService) {
  super();
}
```

```js
// DynamicFormService
public get countriesValidity(): boolean {
  return (
    this.form.controls.countries?.invalid &&
    (this.form.controls.countries?.dirty ||
      this.form.controls.countries?.touched)
  );
}
```

```html
<!-- DynamicFormTemplate -->
<mat-error *ngIf="formService.countriesValidity">
  {{"COMMON.messages.error" | translate}}
</mat-error>
```

The issue is now that `formService.countriesValidity` gets called every time the component is re-rendered – for example if the user opens a dropdown and selects some options.

Another example:

`formService.dynamicFields` returns the controls from `this.form.controls.dynamicFields`.

```html
<div *ngFor="let control of formService.dynamicFields; index as groupIndex">
  <input [formControlName]="groupIndex" placeholder="{{formService.attributes.value[groupIndex]}}">
</div>
```

How do we prevent this? Do we have to prevent that at all? I assume that this can get quite messy once a method has to perform some heavy calulations.

I'm aware that `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` exists but I've figured that this doesn't work well in my case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The reason for this is because countriesValidity is a function call, and you really should try to prevent doing function calls from your template. In this specific case, it is not problematic because you’re not doing much in the getter. But if you have more complex things to do - you should use a pure pipe instead.

Comment: Yes excatly. Using pipes is the only way, isn't it? How would one implement this? There are other methods wich are being called from the template (see update questions).

Comment: Your second example (just like your main one) really isn’t problematic at all. Pipe is one option, another is to monitor the form states in your component (using valueChanges) and setting these combined states as a single component scoped variable you can reference from the template. But again, I would advice not to over-engineer or worry about performance in the kind of scenarios you’ve mentioned.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I just wanted to ensure not to cause major performance issues because I'm quite new to the angular world and do not understand the underlying concepts properly.